# Wifi is connected, but no internet access. (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

Tags: wireless, usb, asus

Recently I've switched to wifi from ethernet and all has been going well for the past day until the next morning. In the top right panel, it says I'm connected but I can't access any websites.

I'm using an ASUS USB-N13 B1 revision adapter with the rtl8192cu driver.

Comment: What is the output of `ifconfig`, `route -n`, and `ping -c5 4.2.2.2`?

Answer (score 0):

If it's connected, then you have 99% changes that it isn't a problem with your computer.
Instead, you should make sure your **router** or modem is working correctly.
In most cases, a LED will indicate wether if you're connected to the Internet or not.

---

If that can't be the case, you need to provide more information, such as:

- Output of `route -n`
- Output of `ifconfig`
- Output of `sudo iptables -L`
- Output of `ping -c5 4.2.2.2` (via @Alaa)

In order for us to be able to better diagnose the problem.